# Only the button in the first row is working in html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an add button in a table for every row, which when clicked should print the price in the price column by multiplying the quantity entered by the user with the price of the product. But it is only working for the 1st row. How do I make it work?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="bg-white">
        <form method="POST">
            <table class="table table-responsive" id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Item</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Qty</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                </tr>

                <body>
                    <?php 
                        $i = 1;
                        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $name => $array){ 
                            $price = "select item_name, Item_price from item where item_name='$array'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $price);
                                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    $name = $rows['item_name']; 
                                    $pr = $rows['Item_price'];
                    ?>

                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $name;?></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="qty" style="width: 40px" name="ss"></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="values()">add</button></td>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function values() {
                            var n1, n2, final;

                            n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty').value);
                            n2 = parseFloat(<?php echo $pr ?>);
                            final = n1*n2;
                            alert(final);
                            document.getElementById('qty').value = n1;
                            document.getElementById('val') = final;
                        }
                                          </script>

                    <td id="val"></td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-    danger btn_remove">X</button></td>
                </tr>
                                     <?php 
                        }
                    $i++;
                        } 
                    ?>

                </body>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should also be using `tbody` not `body`

Comment: From  [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) "_The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document._". `id="qty"` is not unique.

Comment: so how should I make it unique? @DinoCoderSaurus

Answer (score 0):

You should first and foremost use prepared statements as mentioned in the comments. Make it a habit. Do it every time. It is important. And correct the tag issue.

You need to know that the function `values` is re-defined at every iteration of the loop, so all calculations are using the price of the last item. You should define the function exactly once. You should consider changing it to accept arguments, eg  price and name. It will become clear why as you read on.

You could make the id's unique for each `qty` and `val` by adding the "name". Instead of
 `<input class="form-control" type="text" id="qty" ...`
 try something like
`<input class="form-control" type="text" id="<?php echo $name.'_qty'; ?>" ...`.

And something similar for the `val` id.

Now, have the onclick take arguments, so instead of `onclick="values()"` when the button is created, something like `onclick="values(<?php echo '\''.$name.'\','.$pr; ?>)"` [all the ticks and \ are to quote the name, maybe there's a better way!].

The (one) `values` function can take the two arguments (`function values(name,price) {`), and it can "construct" the ids something like this
 `n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(name + '_qty').value);`

The code I've supplied is sample only and not guaranteed syntax error free. You have a lot of typing and testing and retyping and retesting ahead of you. Slow and steady......